# Failing to install Google Chrome stable using a docker script

Tags: package-management, dpkg, google-chrome, docker

Im using a Dockerfile to run an Ubuntu container with Chrome and some other apps, this is how it looks:

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04
ENV USER=root
ENV PASSWORD=password1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
RUN apt-get update && \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select America" > ~/tx.txt && \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/America select New York" >> ~/tx.txt && \
    debconf-set-selections ~/tx.txt && \
    apt-get install -y abiword gnupg apt-transport-https wget software-properties-common ratpoison novnc websockify libxv1 libglu1-mesa xauth x11-utils xorg tightvncserver && \
    wget https://kumisystems.dl.sourceforge.net/project/virtualgl/2.6.5/virtualgl_2.6.5_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://kumisystems.dl.sourceforge.net/project/turbovnc/2.2.7/turbovnc_2.2.7_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i virtualgl_*.deb && \
    dpkg -i turbovnc_*.deb && \
    mkdir ~/.vnc/ && \
    mkdir ~/.dosbox && \
    echo $PASSWORD | vncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd && \
    chmod 0600 ~/.vnc/passwd && \
    echo "set border 1" > ~/.ratpoisonrc  && \
    echo "exec google-chrome --no-sandbox">> ~/.ratpoisonrc && \
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ~/novnc.pem -out ~/novnc.pem -days 3650 -subj "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NY/O=NY/OU=NY/CN=NY emailAddress=email@example.com"
EXPOSE 80
CMD /opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncserver && websockify -D --web=/usr/share/novnc/ --cert=~/novnc.pem 80 localhost:5901 && tail -f /dev/null
```

The relevant lines are:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I'm getting this error:

```
#5 73.69 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
#5 73.69 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
#5 73.69 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
#5 73.69 or been moved out of Incoming.
#5 73.69 The following information may help to resolve the situation:
#5 73.69 
#5 73.69 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
#5 73.75  google-chrome-stable:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.17) but it is not installable
#5 73.75                               Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable
.
.
.
many others
```

I don't get why those dependencies cannot be installed. Following a suggestion I changed the `apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` with `dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` under the logics that dpkg should resolve the dependencies issues, rerun the script getting this new error:

```
#5 105.4 dpkg: error processing archive ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
#5 105.4  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
#5 105.4 Errors were encountered while processing:
#5 105.4  ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Wich I understand even less since I did not see where arm64 is set in the script, maybe is a default option? (Im running Docker in a macOS with a M2 chip)

Comment: So your Docker is running on an ARM machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your architecture is `arm64`, while the script is set to install packages for `amd64`.

Under normal circumstances, this should be pretty straightforward  with a basic search and replace: Replace all instances of `amd64` with `arm64` in the Dockerfile.

*However,* I did the homework for you, and it seems none of the packages you want to download (`virtualgl`, `turbovnc` or `google-chrome-stable`) has an `arm64` package available (at least from those download locations).

You have then requested an impossible situation, by running an `arm64` architecture, but requiring packages only available for `amd64`.

So you have to either:

1. Switch to `amd64` architecture
2. Compile the packages for `arm64` architecture
3. Find alternative packages to achieve what you want